# Defining a pin on an 8 Bit SFR ( special register)

Tags: c, pins

In Infineon C509 there is a register called S1CON which is a special function register which looks like this. 
[image]

Is is possible to define bit 0 on S1CON as RI1 so it can be access and refereed to in the main program. I wanted to checked in my main program if  receive flag interrupt for serial interface 1  is high or low. Its not defined in the header file but S1CON is

```
sfr   S1CON  = 0x9B;
```

Thank you

Or is it just possible to just check the status on Bit 0 on S1CON???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define masks for the individual bits (they may already be defined for you in an appropriate header file), e.g.

```
#define RI1  0x01 // RI1 = bit 0
#define TI1  0x02 // TI1 = bit 1
#define RB81 0x04 // RB81 = bit 2
...
```

and then to test RI1:

```
if (SC1CON & RI1)
    ...
```

To set RI1:

```
SCICON |= RI1;
```

To clear RI1:

```
SCICON &= ~RI1;
```

Comment: The problem is that S1CON is defined at = 0x50 in order to set up UART1, so this way will most likely affect that setup, wouldn't it??

Comment: No - you're just reading the register and testing bit 0 - it won't modify the register contents.

Comment: Oh i see so if i wanted to if RI1 is equal to one 'if ((S1CON & RI1)==1)` should work

Comment: Would this method work if you wanted to change the status on the pin??? change it to 1 or 0

Comment: Yes - I've now updated the answer to include set and clear examples.